# Play framework memory usage

Tags: playframework

I would like to ask you about your experience with play framework and it's memory usage. The thing is that I'm looking for a hosting for my play project (with Scala) and I'm a poor student so i need something as cheap as possible. I was thinking of renting a cloud server at rackspace with 256mb ram and play on ubuntu-server ed. behind glassfish. Do you guys have any opinions?

Thanls for the answers!

Comment: So you've created your project already? Why not host it on your development machine temporarily, simulate a bunch of client connections, and just see how much memory it uses?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The basic hosting service on PlayApps.net only has 64Mb RAM and it works very well. As already pointed out, this is what runs the playframework site, and it serves 100,000 requests per day.

I have also run on Google App Engine, and it tends to use around 60-70 Mb. However, I would point out, that if you are running inside a WAR file on Glashfish, you are probably going to have a lot of added overhead that you don't need (all the J2EE enabled stuff that is just not needed).

I would suggest using a lightweight HTTP server sat in front of the standard play server. This will minimise your memory useage.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about GAE, but i feel i have enough learning to do already, with being newbie in both play framework and scala :] I will consider the playapps.net. Thanks!

Comment: GAE has many restrictions which I therefore would not suggest if you want to use some of the cool features of play. As a simple site though, it works good enough

Comment: I've had experience on a Play app that was initially targeted to use GAE. In the end, we had to switch to "normal" Play and server, as with GAE we kept spending time fixing issues and doing workarounds (that would trigger other issues). As @Codemwnci says, GAE can be cool for simple stuff, but for a decent web app, trust me, go normal Play. Your project will save time and yourself stress :)

Comment: due to Heroku supporting Play natively, without the need for a WAR deployment, the team decided to discontinue playapps.net. I think their current site is based on cloudbees;

Answer (score 6):

Try the play hosting service : http://www.playapps.net/

The playframework website use the basic slot with 100.000 request by day

Comment: Interesting, i saw the playapps site but i felt it's kind of a ripoff, with 64mb ram for 10euro. I didn't know they use it for the playframework.net, though! I will consider it. Thanks!

Comment: @Arg although it seems a ripoff, you should think that you won't need a sysadmin for your server, nor to spend your time managing stuff like server security, backups, etc... How much does that cost for you? ;)

Comment: Yep, that's a pretty good point. Don't get me wrong, though, i had no idea that play use so little memory that 64mega would be enough for so many hits ^_^